# Group Theory Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$F : \Bbb Z_n^*\to\Bbb Z_n^*$ is a group homomorphism.

$F[x]= [x^2]$

Find $\ker F$.

Here $\Bbb Z_n^*=\{[k]\in\Bbb Z_n:\gcd(k,n)=1\}$.

Please help me with proof!

Comment: You haven't said what you are trying to prove, so it's difficult to help you with it!

Comment: Suggest you try some examples to get a feeling for the problem. Try some examples with $n$ a prime, a product of two primes, a power of 2, etc. $n=24$ is instructive.

Comment: Derek Holt, I'm trying to find the set Ker F!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $F([1])=[1]=F([n-1])$, so $[1],[n-1]\in\ker F$.

**Note:** This was my answer for one of the several earlier versions of the question, which was to show that $\ker F=\{[1],[n-1]\}$. I’d have given a somewhat different hint for the present version, which is to find $\ker F$.

Comment: Please suggest!

Comment: @user85221: The hint is still valid for this version of the problem. It’s just that it’s a bigger hint than I would have given had you posted this version first.

Comment: Can you help me prove when n= p^2 (p is prime)?

Comment: @user85221: The question that you’ve posted has the same answer for all $n>2$: if $n>2$, it’s always true that $[1]$ and $[n-1]$ are distinct elements of $\ker F$, so if $|\ker F|=2$, then $\ker F$ must be equal to $\{[1],[n-1]\}$.